# Which version of SQL Server CE does SQL Server 2014 supports?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, sql-server-ce-4

I'm using SQL Server CE for SQL Server 2008. But, now I must using SQL Server 2014, But SQL Server CE 3.5 SP.2 doesn't support SQL Server 2014.

Which version of SQL Server CE does SQL Server 2014 support?

Comment: The full SQL Server and SQL Server CE are totally **independent** - no *full* version of SQL Server "supports" a specific version of SQL Server CE .... your question is very unclear....

Answer (score -1):

Are you talking about Merge Replication? In that case, SQL Server 2014 does not support Merge Replication with SQL Server Compact, the last version of SQL Server to do this is SQL Server 2012